# mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Script too big) - multichain - blockchain

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I issued 8000 to 15000 assets for 1 address in a loop, and when i'm trying to transfer all assets to set of other addresses some are not transferred and it gives error **"Error Code: -26 Error Message: Transaction was rejected: ConnectInputs failed: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Script too big)"**

> From my research, i found that some assets were transferred to the
>   same address successfully and others are not getting transferred.
>
> All addresses have connect, send and receive permissions

Can anyone suggest me a solution for this

Comment: What kind of script are you constructing? Why not use standard scripts and just have multiple outputs per tx?

Comment: we are using top-level command "SENDASSETFROM" to transfer from one address to another address, but some are transferred and some are not.

we didn't construct any scripts.

can you suggest any solution?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were using Bitcoin, I am unfamiliar with multichain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get answer from the Multichain Admin in their forum, please find the answer in this link
https://www.multichain.com/qa/15183/mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed-script-too-big

> OK, so we've found the cause of this, thanks for all the information. It's actually a bug that will be fixed in the next protocol upgrade.
>
> If this is not yet a live system, you can solve the problem by starting a new blockchain with the following parameter setting (edit params.dat before starting the chain):
>
> `max-std-element-size=1024`